# How to get ts_headline to respect phraseto_tsquery

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.6

I have a query that uses phrase search to match whole phrases.

```sql
SELECT ts_headline(
  'simple',
  'This is my test text. My test text has many words. Well, not THAT many words.',
  phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'text has many words')
);
```

Which results in:

```
This is my test <b>text</b>. My test <b>text</b> <b>has</b> <b>many</b> <b>words</b>. Well, not THAT <b>many</b> <b>words</b>.
```

But I would have expected this:

```
This is my test text. My test <b>text</b> <b>has</b> <b>many</b> <b>words</b>. Well, not THAT many words.
```

Or ideally even this:

```
This is my test text. My test <b>text has many words</b>. Well, not THAT many words.
```

Sidenote:

```
phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'text has many words')
```

is equivalent to

```
to_tsquery('simple', 'text <-> has <-> many <-> words')
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if ts_headline simply does not support this kind of highlighting.

Answer (score 6):

`phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'text has many words')` generates correct query but it seems the problem is in `ts_headline` function. Seems like an already reported BUG [#155172](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/152461454026.19805.6310947081647212894@wrigleys.postgresql.org).

Answer (score 0):

I am writing an extension that improves the ts_headline functionality to correctly highlight matching phrases with single tag, while not highlighting partial matches. The extension in available at https://github.com/thevermeer/pg_ts_semantic_headline and is intended to replace ts_headline directly.

Usage:

```
SELECT ts_semantic_headline(
  'simple',
  'This is my test text. My test text has many words. Well, not THAT many words.',
  phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'text has many words')
);
```

which produces:

| ts_semantic_headline |
| --- |
| This is my test text. My test <b>text has many words.</b> Well, not THAT many words. |

The `ts_semantic_headline` solution is uses `ts_headline` under the hood to produce content fragments, and then uses text parsing and customized TSVectors, along with the included `ts_fast_headline` function to perform multi-word highlighting with minimal (5-10%) performance cost on top of ts_headline.

If performance is of any concern, the `ts_fast_headline` function can also use 2 pre-processed columns (TSPVector + TEXT[]), and deliver highlighted content 5X-10X faster than ts_headline.